# Interfacing web crawler with Django front end

Tags: python, django, web-crawler

I'm trying to do three things.

One: crawl and archive, at least daily, a predefined set of sites.

Two: run overnight batch python scripts on this data (text classification).

Three: expose a Django based front end to users to let them search the crawled data.

I've been playing with Apache Nutch/Lucene but getting it to play nice with Django just seems too difficult when I could just use another crawler engine.

Question [950790](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950790/use-django-framework-with-website-and-stand-alone-app) suggests I could just write the crawler in Django itself, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Basically - any pointers to writing a crawler in Django or an existing python crawler that I could adapt? Or should I incorporate 'turning into Django-friendly stuff' in step two and write some glue code? Or, finally, should I abandon Django altogether? I really need something that can search quickly from the front end, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you insert your django project's app directories into sys.path, you can write standard Python scripts that utilize the Django ORM functionality.  We have an /admin/ directory that contains scripts to perform various tasks-- at the top of each script is a block that looks like:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../my_django_project'))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../../'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

Then it's just a matter of using your tool of choice to crawl the web and using the Django database API to store the data.

Answer (score 2):

You write your own crawler using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to get the pages and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML looking for the content.

Here's an example of reading a page:

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples

Here's an example of parsing the page:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing HTML

Comment: In my experience, lxml2 (http://codespeak.net/lxml/) works a lot faster than BeautifulSoup. I don't currently have any proof benchmarks, though.

Comment: @drdaeman: I don't have experience with lxml2, but BeautifulSoup's strong point is its error tolerance. Since web pages famously contain errors.

Comment: In my experience, lxml2 works pretty good with malformed HTML. And if something goes really wrong it can use BeautifulSoup as a parser (http://codespeak.net/lxml/elementsoup.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write crawler using Django ORM (or already have working crawler) you could share database between crawler and Django-powred front-end.

To be able to search (and edit) existing database using Django admin you should create Django models.
The easy way for that is described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/